# What do you call someone made an offer?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

If someone made an offer, what English word define such person?

Offerer?

The more the better.

Comment: It depends on what kind of offer is made for what type of context or business. Context, please. Unless you edit your question, your question will be closed and deleted. Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*.

Comment: The more the better, I will find out which one is best suit

Comment: Do you see the downvote? I am not the downvoter, but your question is off-topic. You received two close-votes 10 minutes after you posted your question. It's up to you whether to edit it or not. We are not your thesaurus service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Bidder](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bidder)*** is a term often used in professional contexts:

> - someone who ​offers to ​pay a ​particular ​amount of ​money for something:
>
>   - *In an ​auction, ​goods or ​property are ​sold to the ​highest bidder (= the ​person who ​offers the most ​money).*

(Cambridge Dictionary)